# how to fix the incorrect dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Iam working on binary image classification problem using supervised machine learning.
I used svm classifier algorithm. First I created a numpy array for normalized color images in a variable X,whose shape is (17500,32,32,3). Then after data splitting, X_train has the shape (14000,32,32,3)  and dimension 4 and y_train has the shape (14000,2) and dimension 2.

```
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

After running this code I got an value error: Found array of dimension 4 estimator has dimension <=2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using scikit-learn SVM classification algorithm, it expects 2D arrays of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` for the training dataset for a [SVM fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit) function.

The dataset you are passing in is a 4D array, therefore you need to reshape the array into a 2D array.

Example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# To apply a classifier, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix, 
# assuming data is numpy array of shape (17500, 32, 32, 3), convert to shape (17500, 3072).
n_samples = len(data)
data_reshape = data.reshape((n_samples, -1))

# Split data into train and test subsets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_reshape, labels, 
                                                    test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called **Dimensionality Reduction**. Mapping data from high dimensional space into lower dimensions. The most commonly used technique is the **Principal Component Analysis(PCA)**. You can learn about them through the following links :

- https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-and-dimensionality-reduction-f488d1a035de
- https://www.quora.com/What-dimensionality-reduction-methods-would-you-recommend

  This link explains reduction with an example which has a dataset similar to yours : https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/principal-component-analysis-in-python